# WPF: How do I disable the SystemMenu shortcut 'Alt+Space'?

Tags: wpf, space, systemmenu, alt-key

I have a borderless window and created the chrome but I need to disable the 'Alt+Space' shortcut.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's very bad practise to disable system shortcuts. I would personally uninstall an application that tried to mess with Alt-Space. Just an FYI.

Comment: Thanks Richard but I was handling system shortcut to implement it myself.  Same keys, added functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not very good with WPF, but after some messing around, this seems to be on the right track. Just throw it in your Window code-behind:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && e.SystemKey == Key.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cory.  I just spent 6 hours sizing and moving a borderless form with KeyDown (arrows & Ctrl, etc).  You'd think this would occur to me?!?  :-) Thanks again.